# How to find the index to be insterted in array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

How to find the index to be insterted in array of object.

I have array of Object.

```
var cordinate =  [
[225, 242],
[405, 242],
[585, 242],
[765, 242],
[225, 325],
[405, 325],
[585, 325],
[765, 325],
[225, 408],
[405, 408],
[585, 408],
[765, 408]
]
```

Here i want to nearest element to be inserted

array which i want to insert

```
var extraEle = [404, 260]
```

How to detremine the exact index for the extraEle in cordinate.

Here is what I am trying

I am comparing y cordinate to get the nearest range and then comparing x cordinate with only y range to get index.

```
 var yValue = [];
var diffVal = cordinate[0][1];
for(var i=0; i<cordinate.length;i++){
    if (Math.abs(extraEle[1] - diffVal) > Math.abs(extraEle[1]- cordinate[i][1])){
        diffVal = componentsPos[i][1];
    }
}
var index;
yvalue = [];
for(var i=0; i<cordinate.length;i++){
    if (cordinate[i][1] === diffVal){
        yvalue.push(componentsPos[i]);
    }
}

var diffValX = yvalue[0][0];
for(var i=0; i<yvalue.length;i++){
    if (Math.abs(extraEle[0] - diffValX) > Math.abs(extraEle[0]- yvalue[i][0])){
        diffValX = yvalue[i][0];
    }
}

var indexValue = [diffValX,diffVal]
cordinate.indexOf(indexValue, 0)
```

Can we have something inbuilt or better approach than this.
**Note : This code is working code.**

The output in my case will be **2** because 260(**Y**) will be in range of first 4 element and 404 (**X**) will come before third element.

After adding my cordinate should be like.

```
cordinate =  [
[225, 242],
[405, 242],
[404, 260],
[585, 242],
[765, 242],
[225, 325],
[405, 325],
[585, 325],
[765, 325],
[225, 408],
[405, 408],
[585, 408],
[765, 408]

]
```

But precisely I need only index where I can insert.

Comment: What do you want your expected output to look like? Also I'm presuming `cordinate` is an array as opposed to an object?

Comment: In your first block of code, `cordinate` is not an array of objects, nor is it valid javascript. Can you please update it with valid JS?

Comment: yes, cordinated is a collection of array. In Out I want the approximate index where I can add my variable in the cordinate. @Jack

Comment: @David it's still unclear what the logic for inserting the new element is. Can you please make this a bit more clear and add your expected output (final value of `cordinate`) as well please?

Comment: @JackBashford I have updated the question. I am comparing y cordinate to get the nearest range and then comparing x cordinate.

Comment: So in order to determine where to add a coordinate: 1. determine which of the 3 groups has the least difference between Y: 260 - 242,  2. Then the find the next highast X? It should be before 405 not 585? Makes very little sense.

Comment: @zer00ne true, it not coming perfectly, but technically the ask is how to determine the nearest index in array of array from the given variable in two dimension. In one 1D is completly fine. getting the nearest element in cordinate by the given vaiable in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic as I understand is:

Find the sub-arrays that is closest in value of `y` and then `X` more accurately. Note: OP's example of desired output is wrong:

> ```
> [405, 242], [404, 260], [585, 242],...
> ```

`[404, 260]` should be placed before `[405, 242]`.

In the example below:

- 2 array of arrays are created from x and y values.

> ```
> [[x, (x - 404)],...] and [[y, (y - 260)],...]
> ```

Then each sub-array is sorted by index 1 and from that we derive the closest `[x, y]`

```js
let coords = [[225,242],[405,242],[585,242],[765,242],[225,325],[405,325],[585,325],[765,325],[225,408],[405,408],[585,408],[765,408]];

let add = [404, 260];

const findRange = (array, xy) => {
  let xArr = [];
  let yArr = [];
  for (let sub of array) {
    xArr.push([sub[0], Math.abs(xy[0] - sub[0])]);
    yArr.push([sub[1], Math.abs(xy[1] - sub[1])]);
  }
  let xRng = xArr.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
  let yRng = yArr.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
  let X = xRng[0][0];
  let Y = yRng[0][0];
  let closest = [X, Y];
  let idx = array.flatMap((s, i) => closest[0] === s[0] && closest[1] === s[1] ? i : []); 
  if (X >= xy[0]) {
    array.splice(idx, 0, xy);
  } else {
    array.splice(idx+1, 0, xy);
  }
  return array;
};
  
    
console.log(findRange(coords, add));
```

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it will determine the closest coordinate, by calculating the distance between the points and determining the closest one, then you can just `splice` it into the array.

```js
// Input coordinates
let coordinates = 
[
  [225, 242],
  [405, 242],
  [585, 242],
  [765, 242],
  [225, 325],
  [405, 325],
  [585, 325],
  [765, 325],
  [225, 408],
  [405, 408],
  [585, 408],
  [765, 408]
];

// Add this to the array
let extraEle = [404, 260];

getClosestIndex(coordinates, extraEle).then((result) => {
  coordinates.splice(result, 0, extraEle);
  console.log(coordinates);
  // Output
  /*[
      [225, 242],
      [405, 242],
      [404, 260]
      [585, 242],
      [765, 242],
      [225, 325],
      [405, 325],
      [585, 325],
      [765, 325],
      [225, 408],
      [405, 408],
      [585, 408],
      [765, 408]
    ]; */
});

function getClosestIndex(coords, targetCoords) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
    let shortestDist = 999999999;
    let shortestIndex = 0;
    coords.forEach((coord, index) => {  
      let dist = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((coord[0]-targetCoords[0]), 2) 
                           + Math.pow((coord[1]-targetCoords[1]), 2));
      if (dist < shortestDist) {
          shortestDist = dist;
          shortestIndex = index;
      } 
    });
     // To add it after the closest element
    if (shortestIndex < coords.length - 1)
      shortestIndex += 1;
    resolve(shortestIndex);
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer carel.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a funny solution.

Given a simple function that finds the closest value in an array, find the nearest Y value. Then all you have to do is add the new coordinate to the array and sort by Y then X column. When sorting the new coordinate treat its Y value as the nearest Y value.

```js
let coords = [[225,242],[405,242],[585,242],[765,242],[225,325],[405,325],[585,325],[765,325],[225,408],[405,408],[585,408],[765,408]];
let add = [404, 260];

const closestValue = (array, goal) => 
   array.reduce((prev, curr) => 
    Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);

let nearestY = closestValue(coords.map(c => c[1]), add[1]);

coords.push(add);
coords.sort(function([a, b], [c, d]) {
  if(b === add[1]){
    b = nearestY;
  } else if(d === add[1]){
    d = nearestY;
  }  
  return b - d || a - c   
});

console.log(coords);
```

I believe the sort can be improved.

Comment: Haha.. Actually in the begninig i was looking for some kind of solution which precisely give me some algo where i can fit my variable. though i was not getting any idea so i started calculating with Y value and then moved to X value itteration.